# IIS Error 'Could not find stored procedure 'MyProcedure'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, iis

I checked other posts with a similar title, but nothing suggested has worked for me.

Using SQL Server 2014, VS2015 and IIS 8.0.9

Application works perfectly when launched in VS, but fails when deployed to IIS with the above error. The web page contains a drop down box and a start and end date textboxes. User can select hospital from drop down and enter start and end date criteria, click on a button and the results are returned in a gridview control. As I said, this functions perfectly in VS.

When I login to my IIS server, open IIS navigate to my application and select 'browse' from the options and try to navigate to this particular web page, the error is generated. All other functionality works as expected.

What I've tried:

1. Have checked spelling of  stored procedure and it's correct
2. Have checked login credentials of user in my connection string by logging in to SSMS using same credentials and executing stored procedure. 
   Can do both both.
3. Checked user permissions to stored procedure. User is a member of 'db_execute' role, which I think is OK
4. Have checked that login credentials match those in IIS. They do as all other functionality is working and they all use the same login credentials
5. Have run a SQL Profiler trace. It doesn't find any issues that I can see
6. Have deleted and re-created the stored procedure a number of times. No change
7. Have removed the application from IIS and recreated. No change
8. Have installed on a server running a different version of IIS (6). Same error
9. Scratched head and ran out of ideas....
10. Ready to throw computer through window

T-SQL

```
    @HospitalID INT = NULL,
    @StartSamplingDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @EndSamplingDate DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        DNASCreeningID, Surname, Forename, DoB, T21DNAResult, T18DNAResult, 
        T13DNAResult, SamplingDate
    FROM 
        tblPatients
    WHERE 
        (@HospitalID IS NULL OR HospitalID = @HospitalID)
        AND ((@StartSamplingDate IS NULL) OR SamplingDate >= @StartSamplingDate)
        AND ((@EndSamplingDate IS NULL) OR SamplingDate <= @EndSamplingDate)
    ORDER BY 
        DNAScreeningID ASC
END
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions or ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct database? I would hazard a guess that you're connecting to a different database to where the stored procedure is. it's not a permission issue, as that would result in a different error. Also, that has the "smell" of a catch-all query, which can perform horribly: [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the IDE?

Comment: @Larnu. Yes, I'm connecting to the correct database.

Comment: @Prescott Chartier. If you mean in Visual Studio, then yes. The page works as expected and returns the expected results given the criteria selected.

Comment: It depends on the connection string you use. If you chose Windows authentication, then when running in VS the app uses your logon credentials, while on IIS it uses the application identity. The two scenarios are completely different, and your database access control can simply block the latter.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for some extraordinary measures.  When I run into issues like this I use logging to track down the issue.  It's a pain in a$$ but necessary if the app works in the IDE but not on IIS, also you may want to add some sort of logging to the stored procedure/database to know when it's logged into and what procedures are executed.  I use Oracle, so I don't know what kind of logging is available naturally in Sql server, you may have to write your own.

Comment: Please run this query: select user, system_user from your application and post the result here

Comment: @sepupic We've had a campus-wide power failure and systems are slow coming back online. Will post when systems are back

Comment: @sepupic We've had a campus-wide power failure and systems are slow coming back online. Will post when systems are back

Comment: My suspect is even if you executed the code from the same user in VS, the real user that executes the code from application is another one. There can be variuos reasons because it can happen, but first I wanted to check if it's the case.

Comment: @sepupic. I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure why this would be the case for **just this** stored procedure, when all other stored procedures work fine.

Comment: Did you execute the code? Did you get login/user as expected?

Comment: @sepupic result is 'DNAScreeningUser', which is the sql server user I use in my connection string. Is this what you expected?

Comment: So DNAScreeningUser is e login, and it's also a user, correct? Can you also execute SELECT DB_NAME() from your application?

Comment: 'DNAScreeningUser' is a SQL Server login I use. It is a member of 'db_execute' role as I said above.

Comment: Also executed second query, which gives me 'DNAScreening', which is the name of the database I'm connecting to.

Comment: The connection string was pointing to the SQL Server using the Server name. I changed this to the IP address of the machine and everything is working as it should.

Comment: Also used 'ipconfig /flushdns' from a command line to refresh DNS. Can now refer to the hostname instead of IP address in my connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database connection if may possible your connection is set to wrong application